# Need more contrast on the close screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Example]

See the text right in the middle, above the "[14] Is wikia.com general reference? (2)"? Can you read it? Because I can't. The highlighted text below the same line is the same color, for reference.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. My eyes.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of design changes to the site, this is no longer an issue.